# Check if element exists or not

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a code that grabs a price tag from this HTML section

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="cost-box">
        <ins><span>$</span><price>10.00</price></ins>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code I use to get the `10.00` price:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.sample.com/sample/123abcd"

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(response, "html.parser")

container = soup.find("div", class_="cost-box")
price = container.price    # <-- get <price> tag from container
print(price.text)
```

The only problem though is that some pages doesn't have prices on them and would only have something like this in their HTML:

```
<div class="cost-box">
   
</div>
```

And my code would now give an error saying

```
price = container.price.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Is there a way to add some sort of a checkpoint on whether the `price` variable exists? Instead of having the error and the whole program coming to a stop, I just want the `price` to say `invalid` and the code would still continue (I placed it on a for loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if-else`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# price missing:
html_text = """
<div class="main">
    <div class="cost-box">

    </div>
</div>"""

soup = bs(html_text, "html.parser")

container = soup.find("div", class_="cost-box")
price = container.price.text if container.price else "Invalid"
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
Invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if container exists first with `if container`. This avoids errors if that div is missing entirely.Then check if `container.find("price")` returns a result before assigning to price. If no  tag is found, set price to "Invalid" instead.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sample.com/sample/123abcd"

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

container = soup.find("div", class_="cost-box")

if container and container.find("price"):
    price = container.find("price").text
else:
    price = "Invalid"

print(price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the text from the `div` tag and not the `price` tag, which will just return an empty string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="main">
    <div class="cost-box">
        <ins><span>$</span><price>10.00</price></ins>
    </div>
    <div class="cost-box">
    </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
cost_box = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'cost-box'})

print([cost.text.strip() for cost in cost_box]) # --> ['$10.00', '']
```